# TypeError: Type error in Javascript when assigning a value to a multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, sqlite

I am having a weird error and I've spent my whole day just to figure it out my self but I give up :) The code below is in a function that gets data from an SQLite database and assign the results in a multidimensional array then the function returns this array. This actually works but when the rows from the database is 3 and above the error below shows. I'm sure the assigned values for each is consistent throughout the loop because I tried to use typeof to know the type. Please help me. Thanks!

> TypeError: Type error

```
 var db = openDB();
 var arrItems = [[],[]];

 db.transaction(function(tx) {
    var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM items WHERE category=?;', [txtcategory]);
    arrItems.length = rs.rows.length;

   for(var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {

      arrItems[i][0] = rs.rows.item(i).category;
      arrItems[i][1] = rs.rows.item(i).date;
      arrItems[i][2] = rs.rows.item(i).descr;
      arrItems[i][3] = rs.rows.item(i).descrlong;
      arrItems[i][4] = rs.rows.item(i).value;
      }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your multidimensional array (really just an array of arrays) is declared to only have two rows:

```
var arrItems = [[],[]];
```

This is why it fails when you have 3 or more rows.  Rather than declare it statically, you should probably add a new row within your loop. So

```
var arrItems = [];
```

And then later, something like

```
arrItems[i] = []
```

Depending on what you're doing, you might want to first check whether the row already exists.

Comment: ah I thought what I did was to declare a two dimensional array with no specified length yet.Sorry I'm new with javascript.Can you elaborate more your suggestion? How can i add a new row to the array? thanks UPDATE: Nevermind I got it now. Thank you so much!